# SPSS - Type of Question

Tags: spss

> I resolved the following question but
>   I have another issue. I would like to
>   analyse "Likert Scale" questionaire
>   which is measured 1 to 5 ( agree,
>   strongly agree etc ). I tried many
>   ways but I didn't combine all results.
>   Have you got any idea to analyze
>   likert scale?

---

Does anybody help us to define following type of question in SPSS variable view?
( looks like array question, user answers non unique which they can enter text  )

**QUESTION 1:**

```
Allows a table of text inputs
+----------------------------------------------+
|            Speed     Design      Accuracy    |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Google   |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Yahoo    |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Bing     |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Please rephrase it!

Comment: @djhurio I changed the question, could you please check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I know what you are asking, but I believe you are looking for some guidance as to what the "dataset" might need to look like.  If you run the following syntax, you should get a better idea of how I would structure it.

```
DATA LIST LIST (",") / browser (A30) type (A30) score.
BEGIN DATA  
Google, Speed, 123
Yahoo, Speed, 34
Bing, Design, 23
Google, Accuracy, 231
Yahoo, Design, 12
END DATA.
```

Comment: I resolved my above question but I have another issue. I would like to analyse "Likert Scale" questionaire which is measured 1 to 5 ( agree, strongly agree etc ). I tried many ways but I didn't combine all results. Have you got any idea to analyze likert scale?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Fortunately, it is easy to solve ;)
If you have your data in the table - you have to "restructure" it (Menu - Data - Restructure). This option allows you to create multidimansional variables. You can find some tutorial on youtube for data restructuring.
In your case, you have to make it manually. You just repeat your identifying variable accordng to the amount of likert scale questions. Let's assume you have 3 questions to "Speed", 3 questions to "Design", and 3 questions to "Accuracy". Your table should look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|            Speed1     Speed2      Speed3     | Duration1 | Duration2 | ...
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Google   |         |          |              |           |           |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Yahoo    |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Bing     |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

You can restructure the data later to perform statistical analysis.
In the case of repeated measurement (e.g. you asked your Likert scale question in the same company 3 times over time), your table might look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|            Speed1     Speed2      Speed3     | Duration1 | Duration2 | ...
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Google   |         |          |              |           |           |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Google   |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Google   |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Yahoo    |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Yahoo    |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Yahoo    |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
| Bing     |         |          |              |
+----------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

...

I hope, it helped!

Best,
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

Likert scale data should be analyzed using non-parametric methods.  Two ways to handle this.

1). Rank the cases and then perform ANOVA on the ranked values

2). Perform Kruskal Wallis on the Likert scale data

Regards